# How to open Google Drive and Google Plus links with my non-primary Google account?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-plus

My personal email is my primary Google account. But my company uses Google enterprise, and colleagues are always sharing Google Plus and Google Drive links with me. When I click them, I usually see something like this:

[image: "You do not have permission to view this album"]

I find that for some Drive links I can manipulate the URL so that it opens with my work account and thus grant me access. For instance, I can change this:

> https://drive.google.com/drive/u/**0**/#folders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX...

to this:

> https://drive.google.c0m/drive/u/**1**/#folders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX...

and I'll get in. But not all Drive URLs follow this convention, and Google Plus URLs appear to have a different construction altogether. And switching accounts while on a Plus page redirects me to my Plus homepage.

Is there any way to ensure that I open Google Plus and Google Drive links with my secondary Google account? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If I have a need to for quick access to multiple Google accounts (work and home, for instance) I'll almost always use a second browser. Usually I'll use Google Chrome for my personal stuff, and Firefox for work.

Another way to manage it is to right-click the link and choose "Open link in incognito window". (Chrome, but just about every other browser has an equivalent feature.) Sure, you'll be prompted to log in, but you shouldn't lose track of where the link leads once you do.

Comment: [Chrome profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en) are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your colleagues to share links to your so-called primary account.

Or log in to a different browser with your secondary account, and manually copy and paste the shared links into a new tab there.

Answer (score 0):

For a more up to date answer: I believe if you use the "Get shareable link" option and not just copy and paste the URL from the browser you will get a valid URL that can be appropriately shared even for those using multiple accounts.